# Mostrar la foto de un contacto en Android

Tags: android, android-glide

Obtengo las fotos de los contactos con:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI)
```

Devuelve la ruta de la foto:

```
content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/1449
```

¿Cómo puedo leerla y cargarla en un `ImageView`?

Si puede ser con Glide mejor que mejor.

Comment: me parece a mi que es el problema de obtener el uri de la foto, no es el correcto, probare con https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858756/getting-photo-of-a-contact

Comment: El final me funcionaba des de el inicio con Glide, lo que me dado cuenta que tenia tint en el imageview de color blanco y no se me veía nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tienes la uri de la imagen, para cargarla en el `imageView` utiliza el metodo `setImageUri()` del `imageView`.

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI)

imageView.setImageUri(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

La ruta que obtienes es en realidad la [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) de la imagen del contacto:

```
content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/1449
```

En este caso puedes usar el método [setImageURI()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) para cargar directamente la imagen dentro de un `ImageView`, ejemplo:

```
ImageView imageView =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/1449"));
```